# Trying to supply a promise to a service for an AngularJS unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a factory:

```
angular.module('app.user').factory('UserService',
  ['RESTService', 'RESTHTTPService',
  function(RESTService, RESTHTTPService) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.search = function(searchTerm, page, size, sort, callback) {
      return RESTService.User.search({searchTerm: searchTerm, page: page, size: size, sort: sort}).$promise.then(callback);
    };

    return factory;
  }
]);
```

So I needed to mock its RESTService dependency.

```
angular.module('app.user.mock').factory('RESTService',
  ['$q',
  function($q) {
    var factory = { User: {} };

    factory.allUsers = {
      content: [ { firstname: 'Spirou', lastname: 'Fantasio', email: 'spirou@yahoo.se', workPhone: '983743464365' } ],
      page: '1'
    };

    factory.User.search = function() {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      defer.resolve(factory.allUsers);
      return defer;
    };

    return factory;
  }
]);
```

To be used in my unit test:

```
describe('user service repository', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('com.nsn.nitro.project');
    module('app.utils.mock');
  });

  var UserService;
  var RESTService;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_UserService_, _RESTService_) {
    UserService = _UserService_;
    RESTService = _RESTService_;
  }));

  it('should return the list of users', function () {
    var users = null;
    UserService.search('TOTO', 1, 10, 'asc', function(data) {
      users = data.content;
    });
    expect(users).toEqual(RESTService.allUsers.content);
  });

});
```

But it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
        at Object.factory.all (/home/stephane/dev/js/projects/angularjs/nitro-project/app/modules/user/service/repository.js:29:81)
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/stephane/dev/js/projects/angularjs/nitro-project/test/spec/modules/user/service.js:59:17)
```

The mocked RESTService is injected fine in the UserService but the promise property, or rather the $promise property, is undefined.

As the code works fine in production, I would like not to touch the existing UserService and RESTService factories. If possible.

Answer (score 1):

$q's promise doens't have a property named $promise. You can set a one with a reference to the `promise` property:

```
factory.User.get = function() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  defer.resolve(this.allUsers);
  defer.$promise = defer.promise;
  return defer;
};
```

Also, because the test is async, you might need to use jasmine's done parmater (depends on your version):

```
it('should return the list of users', function (done) {
    var users = null;
    UserService.all(1, 10, 'asc', function(data) {
      users = data.content;
      expect(users).toEqual(RESTService.allUsers.content);
      done();
    });      
});
```

Comment: By the way, if you have tips on some good AngularJS testing resources, like a book or site, I'm interested.

Comment: I also wonder why the done(); statement is to be after the expect() one. My first impulse would be to have it before, so as to complete the callback process.

Comment: when you call the done function, you let jasmine know you are done with the test. if you were to put expect after done, jasmine would think this test is over and ignore your expects. sorry i dont have any real profound resource.. just the official sites (angular - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing, jasmine) and whatever i can found by googling

Comment: I think we were off the mark here. I added a console.log inside the callback block and it never shows. The test was successful simply because the expect was never executed.

Comment: what version of jasmine are you using?

Comment: I'm using jasmine 0.1.5

Comment: done was added in version 2.0, so its just ignoring the done parameter. if you can upgrade your version, it'll work. otherwise you have to use runs and waitsFor

Comment: Okay, now I have karma-jasmine at 0.2.2 and jasmine-core at 2.2.0

Comment: However a noob, my gut feeling still tells me the done() statement is not what I should use to synchronize my callback. It feels like this done thing is to time and control tests. I'm now trying to do a $rootScope.$apply(); but no luck.

Comment: Here is how I got my test to pass.   it('should return the list of searched users', function() {
    // Always use this statement so as to avoid the error from the $http service making a request to the application main page
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).respond('');

    var users = null;
    UserService.search('TOTO', 1, 10, 'asc', function(data) {
      users = data.content;
    });
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(users).toEqual(RESTService.allUsers.content);
  }); Is that not too hackish ?

Comment: I wish I didn't have to use the $httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).respond(''); as it is the only way I know of avoiding the dreaded error: Error: Unexpected request: GET modules/user/view/login.html

Comment: hmm yeah its a little hacky.. i think done is cleaner. take a look at their site http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html on the Asynchronous Support part

Comment: I get the impression that using this done is like allowing enough time for the callback to be processed, in a sense, telling the test to wait a bit. Whereas my initial way of doing it with a $rootScope.$digest(); is flushing things asap. Am I right in this picture ?

Comment: On top of it, I get a timeout when using the done: Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: yeah i think you got it.. however i like it more when the test focus on what to test rather on how.. about the timeout, try to put $rootScope.$digest() at the end of the test, i suspect the promise isnt resolved because there is no next tick

Comment: The timeout is when I use the done and comment out the $httpBackend.flush(); statement. Adding the $httpBackend.flush(); at the end of the test takes me back to square one with the error message: Error: Unexpected request...

Comment: did you try putting $rootScope.$apply() at the end of the test?

Comment: Yes I did and it was back to square one as well.

Answer (score 0):

To get the test to pass I needed to do two things:

1- Add a $rootScope.$digest(); right after the service call:

```
  it('should return the list of searched users', function() {
    var users = null;
    UserService.search('TOTO', 1, 10, 'asc', function(data) {
      users = data.content;
    });
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(users).toEqual(RESTService.allUsers.content);
  });
```

2- Add $httpBackend.whenGET(/.html$/).respond(''); to work around the issue of httpBackend generating a call to the ui-router template. I'm discussing this issue in another thread at [How to avoid the 'Error: Unexpected request: GET' every time an AngularJS test does a rootScope.digest() or httpBackend.flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634780/how-to-avoid-the-error-unexpected-request-get-every-time-an-angularjs-test-d)

```
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _UserService_, _RESTService_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    UserService = _UserService_;
    RESTService = _RESTService_;

    // Always use this statement so as to avoid the error from the $http service making a request to the application main page
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).respond('');
  }));
```